# Delete all files from any folder

Tags: c#, system, delete-file

When I delete files manually using right click menu then it is deleted.

But when I run this code:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\My cloud\VM Instances\");
foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
     File.Delete(filePath);
```

I got this error:

> "A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Access to the path 'c:\My cloud\VM Instances\i-7e3cbb19 (manish).cvm' is denied.
>   The thread '' (0xb5c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   'cloud_sync.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled."

So what should I do?

Answer (score 7):

The process that your code is running has different permissions than your interactive login process.  The big hint is that you get an `UnauthorizedAccessException`.

Is this a website?  If so, the ASPNET worker process has by design very limited permissions by default (and it would be dangerous to stray far from that default).

Is this a Windows Service?  If so, by default they also run as a user with very limited permissions.

Comment: Thanks for replying so fast. This is a window service. So how can i run my code with all permissions?

Comment: Thanks for replying so fast. This is a window service. So how can i run my code with all permissions?

Comment: @manish, consider asking separate question, or better yet do search for "windows service account permissions" on a search engine (like http://www.bing.com/search?q=windows+service+account+permissions ).

Comment: You probably don't want to just give you Windows Service all permissions across the board because someone who hacks your service gains too much access.  Instead, segregate the code that needs elevated permission and run only that portion with additional permissions.  See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/105506/Getting-Elevated-Privileges-on-Demand-using-C

Comment: @EricJ. I am very new in this area and this is my 1st system service. I read that link but i didn't get what to do. I am using VS2010. Please help me out.